# Visual Studio Windows Forms Designer keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-forms-designer

Extremely basic question.

Are there common actions I can perform using keyboard shortcuts in the Windows Forms designer in Visual Studio (2008)?

Alternately, could I add my *own* keyboard shortcuts (either through settings or macros)?

It'd really be nice if I could, for example, set a control to dock/undock in its parent container by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. Or if I could set a control's name just by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and typing the name. Things like that.

It's just kind of tedious to click on the item, scroll in the Properties grid to the property I want to change, type the new value, scroll to the next property I want to change, etc. Which is why I have a feeling this functionality is in there already, or is easily configurable, and I just don't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any specific to the Windows Forms Designer.

Here are the general ones: [Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en)

[Automating Repetitive Actions by Using Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h31zbch(VS.90).aspx)

- Go to Tools -> Macros -> Record
  TemporaryMacro <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and
  record your macro.
- Save macro by going to Tools ->
  Macros -> Save TemporaryMacro as
  MyMacro

There are several built-in macros, which can be explored using Macro Explorer, Tools -> Macros -> Macro Explorer

There is also [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this since it answered my question quite perfectly. Now, onto a more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713782/how-can-i-access-the-controls-in-a-windows-forms-designer-window-through-a-vs-mac